# My code in C should ask for data and display it, compiles but doesn't display the results

Tags: c, for-loop, struct

I have the following code, it's supposed to take the data from a txt file map it into the array and then print it, but compiling it doesn't do anything, can you help me check if it has any errors?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_FILAS 100
#define MAX_COLUMNAS 100
int i;
struct carreras {
    char codigo[10];
    char nombre[41][20];
    char prelaciones[100][10];
    char siguientes[100][10];
    char materias[41][10];
};
int main() {
    FILE *archivo;
    struct carreras carreras[MAX_FILAS];
    int fila = 0;

    // Abrir el archivo en modo lectura
    archivo = fopen("mododiablo.txt", "r");

    // Verificar si el archivo se abrió correctamente
    if (archivo == NULL) {
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Leer el contenido del archivo y almacenarlo en el arreglo
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_FILAS; i++) {
        char linea[MAX_COLUMNAS];
        fgets(linea, MAX_COLUMNAS, archivo);

        // Separar la línea en campos
        char *campos[4];
        char *token = strtok(linea, ";");
        int j = 0;
        while (token != NULL) {
            campos[j++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        }

        // Asignar los campos al struct
        strcpy(carreras[i].codigo, campos[0]);
        strcpy(carreras[i].nombre, campos[2]);
        strcpy(carreras[i].prelaciones, campos[1]);
        strcpy(carreras[i].siguientes, campos[3]);
    }
    // Cerrar el archivo
    fclose(archivo);

    // Mostrar el contenido del arreglo por pantalla
    for (i = 0; i < fila; i++) {
        printf("Codigo: %s\n", carreras[i].codigo);
        printf("Nombre: %s\n", carreras[i].nombre);
        printf("Prelaciones: %s\n", carreras[i].prelaciones);
        printf("Siguientes: %s\n", carreras[i].siguientes);
    }

    return 0;
    
}
```

In mododiablo.txt

```
FOC-100;Informatica;TEC-100;ING-100
ACC-220;Administracion de Empresas;FOC-100;ING-243
```

I tried but he didn't throw anything at me, I was hoping the data would be saved

Comment: Except the `codigo` member, all the other members of the structure are arrays of arrays. Using `strcpy` to copy strings to them makes no sense.

Comment: Why do you have all those 2-dimensional arrays in the structure?

Comment: As for your problem, to print the data you have the loop `for (i = 0; i < fila; i++)`, but you never modify `fila`, its value will be zero, so the loop never iterates. A couple of minutes in a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) should have told you that.

Comment: And you can fix that problem by putting `fila = i;` after the loop that reads from the file.

Comment: Regarding the structure members, you have the same problem with the printing of those members. Your compiler should have warned you about that, and if not then you need to enable more warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: And take some time to think about what happens if there are not `MAX_FILAS` lines in the file. You *must* check what [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) *returns*.

Comment: Apologies, I'm a newbie and I tried a lot of different things before I got to this point, that's why the way the fixes, I was able to verify that the problem was "fila", thank you very much, it's a college exercise and I'm halfway through, I really appreciate your help

Comment: `strcpy(carreras[i].prelaciones, campos[1]);` looks like it overflows.

Answer (score 0):

After copying your program, the first thing I checked for was compiler warnings, and there were a few that were referencing issues with the two-dimensional arrays noted in the structure.

```
||=== Build: Release in MapFile (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/MapFile/main.c||In function ‘main’:|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/MapFile/main.c|50|warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h|77|note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[20]’|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/MapFile/main.c|51|warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h|77|note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/MapFile/main.c|52|warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h|77|note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/MapFile/main.c|61|warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/MapFile/main.c|62|warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ [-Wformat=]|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/MapFile/main.c|63|warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ [-Wformat=]|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/MapFile/main.c|36|warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 7 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Basically, what the compiler was complaining about was the improper reference for storage of string data in a two-dimensional array as in this line of code.

```
strcpy(carreras[i].nombre, campos[2]);
```

Also, it had a similar complaint about the referencing of the string data in the subsequent "printf" statements.

And as noted in the good comments, the file line counter variable, "fila", was not being incremented.  This then caused the short-circuiting of the "for" loop printing any information.

With those issues to address, following is a refactored version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_FILAS 100
#define MAX_COLUMNAS 100

int i;

struct carreras
{
    char codigo[10];
    char nombre[41][20];
    char prelaciones[100][10];
    char siguientes[100][10];
    char materias[41][10];
};
int main()
{
    FILE *archivo;
    struct carreras carreras[MAX_FILAS];
    int fila = 0;

    // Open the file in read mode
    archivo = fopen("mododiablo.txt", "r");

    // Check if the file was opened correctly
    if (archivo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Read the contents of the file and store it in the array
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_FILAS; i++)
    {
        char linea[MAX_COLUMNAS];
        if (fgets(linea, MAX_COLUMNAS, archivo) == NULL)
            break;

        // Separate the line into fields
        char *campos[4];
        char *token = strtok(linea, ";");
        int j = 0;
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            campos[j++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        }

        // Assign the fields to the struct
        strcpy(carreras[i].codigo, campos[0]);
        strcpy(carreras[i].nombre[0], campos[2]);                   /* Used the first dimension element of the two-dimensional array    */
        strcpy(carreras[i].prelaciones[0], campos[1]);              /* Used the first dimension element of the two-dimensional array    */
        strcpy(carreras[i].siguientes[0], campos[3]);               /* Used the first dimension element of the two-dimensional array    */

        fila++;                                                     /* This variable needed to be incremented for each file record read */
    }
    // Close the file
    fclose(archivo);

    // Show the content of the arrangement on the screen
    for (i = 0; i < fila; i++)
    {
        printf("Codigo: %s\n", carreras[i].codigo);
        printf("Nombre: %s\n", carreras[i].nombre[0]);              /* Used the first dimension element of the two-dimensional array    */
        printf("Prelaciones: %s\n", carreras[i].prelaciones[0]);    /* Used the first dimension element of the two-dimensional array    */
        printf("Siguientes: %s\n", carreras[i].siguientes[0]);      /* Used the first dimension element of the two-dimensional array    */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Some points to note in the refactored code:

- Just to make it easier for the general population to review and understand the program, various narrative text was translated to English.
- To make the code compile, the "string.h" header file was added so as the string manipulation functions noted in your program would work.
- As noted in the good comments, variable "fila" is incremented as needed.
- And not completely knowing the context of having two-dimensional arrays, the various lines of code that were needing to store data in these arrays were revised to utilize the first dimension element of the appropriate array; you may need to reevaluate the purpose and/or necessity of having those two-dimensional arrays.

Reverse engineering the code to create a test file with data that could be read and evaluated, following is a sample run of the refactored code.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/MapFile/bin/Release$ ./MapFile 
Codigo: Program1
Nombre: Test1
Prelaciones: 1
Siguientes: Narrative #1

Codigo: Program2
Nombre: Test2
Prelaciones: 2
Siguientes: Narrative #2

Codigo: Program3
Nombre: Test3
Prelaciones: 3
Siguientes: Narrative #3

Codigo: Program4
Nombre: Test4
Prelaciones: 4
Siguientes: Narrative #4

Codigo: Program5
Nombre: Test5
Prelaciones: 5
Siguientes: Narrative #5
```

The biggest take-away from this analysis is to always be cognizant of any compiler warnings that are issued to determine if further refinement of the code is needed, and also it would be helpful to acquire further tutorial literature on the language, especially in reference to utilizing multi-dimensional arrays.